# Exception couchdb-lucene

Tags: lucene, couchdb

I'm trying to index documents from couchdb but lucene is throwing the exception as follows:

```
WARN [mobiprofiletest] Exiting after init() raised exception.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.github.rnewson.couchdb.lucene.util.Analyzers.{"PERFIELD"
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
at com.github.rnewson.couchdb.lucene.util.Analyzers.valueOf(Analyzers.java:45)
at com.github.rnewson.couchdb.lucene.util.Analyzers.getAnalyzer(Analyzers.java:176)
at com.github.rnewson.couchdb.lucene.couchdb.View.getAnalyzer(View.java:57)
at com.github.rnewson.couchdb.lucene.DatabaseIndexer.init(DatabaseIndexer.java:835)
at com.github.rnewson.couchdb.lucene.DatabaseIndexer.run(DatabaseIndexer.java:479)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

My design document looks like this:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/fulltextTest",
   "_rev": "11-6121dccd00af8f95a9e222755147ebc8",
   "language": "javascript",
   "fulltext": {
       "fulltextTest": {
           "index": "function(doc) {\n    var ret=new Document(); ret.add(doc.objType); return ret;\n}",
           "analyzer": "perfield:{field_name:\"analyzer_name\"}"
       }
   }
}
```

when I'm starting to query the system

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:5984/_fti/local/mobiprofiletest/_design/fulltextTest/fulltextTest?q=hello"
```

the exception as the above is thrown.

When I remove

```
 "analyzer": "perfield:{field_name:\"analyzer_name\"}"
```

it's working.  But the analyzer is copy-pasted from the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you were meant to simply copy and paste that line.  You should replace `field_name` and `analyzer_name` with *your* field names and the analyzers you wish to use for them:

So,

```
"analyzer": "perfield:{field_name:\"analyzer_name\"}"
```

Should look something like:

```
"Analyzer: "perfield:{content:\"ENGLISH\"}
```

Comment: Yes you are right I copied wrong example. The design document must look like this:    `{
       "_id": "_design/fulltextTest",
       "language": "javascript",
       "fulltext": {
           "fulltextTest": {
               "index": "function(doc) {\n    var ret=new Document(); ret.add(doc.objType); return ret;\n}",
               "analyzer": "perfield:{default:\"keyword\"}"
           }
       }
    } `